How to preload Python packages in VSCode
I set up the Conda environment on a network data volume in order to allow it to be shared across different Docker platforms. As a result, loading Python packages and Intellisense in VSCode cannot be done quickly
I tried using python.autoComplete. reloadModules, but it didn't work

Hello, this may be caused by network or Conda environment loading. If you're running in a Docker container, you can try using vscode's remote development extension, which might mitigate the impact of network latency. You can try using the conda list to list all installed packages, remove unnecessary packages and reduce the size of the conda environment. Try clearing vscode's cache and restarting vscode before refreshing the module by python.autoComplete.reloadModules.

Thank you ! Remote Development for solving my problem

I'm glad I can help you solve the problem, and I've edited this as an answer. If you can, you can set it as an answer. This may be helpful to other community members who are experiencing similar issues.

This could be caused by network or Conda environment loading. If you're running in a Docker container, you can using vscode's remote development extension, which will mitigate the impact of network latency.
